# Apache Tomcat configuration to serve 250 Users

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server, ajp

I've two servers (`A`, `B`). On "`A`" I've Apache as a Web-Server for a Tomcat Application and on Server "`B`" I've another Tomcat Application which is also entertained by the same Apache on server "`A`" additionally I'm using AJP connector also to find out which request goes to what server. Problem comes in when there are approx 60 to 70 users which access application on server `B`. I've 4GB stick plus quad core. As per the log there is no memory error, it says some connection error. Please suggest the best configuration for  approx 100 users or so.

Error Type:

Type 1:

> [Thu Apr 23 16:23:29 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
>   [Thu Apr 23 16:23:29 2015] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Type 2:

> [Mon Apr 20 11:10:06 2015] [warn] child process 946 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM ,

Type 3:

> [Mon Apr 20 11:47:12 2015] [error] (104)Connection reset by peer: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header [Mon Apr 20 11:47:12 2015] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed

Comment: "it says some connection error" - this is really not helpful. What error do you get? What kind of applications are we talking about? You need to provide more information if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: Please add these information to your question, not via comment.

Comment: @germi: If i miss anything please do let me know.

Comment: @germi can you suggest something

Comment: @shA.t you too. Please suggest something.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16394682/4519059) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11868988/4519059) in SO and [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/405893) in SF ;).

Comment: Hi guys, Still looking for better results. Will update the post once get the solution.

Comment: Hi Guys, After so much of "This" and "That" finally we have upgraded the ram from 4GB to 6 GB and its working fine.